# How to insert table into another table in php

Tags: php

table 1

```
|product|price|qty| 
| apple  | 2 | 4 |
|mango   | 4 | 3 |
|orange  | 2 | 1|
```

how to table 1 Insert into Blank table please help me i'm new here in php code.

Blank Table

```
|product|price |qty   |
| null  | null | null |
| null  | null | null |
| null  | null | null |
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have any concept of tables, so it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you mean HTML tables, or database tables?